# Error using Highcharts (>= 8.0.1) function stockChart() in Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

When I use the function `Highcharts.stockChart`, imported from `highcharts/highstock` I got these errors (when clicking):

`highstock.src.js:3417 Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".`
and
`highstock.src.js:3417 Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".`

If I use highcharts version 8.0.0 (or 7.1.2) I don't get any errors.

I initially thought that these errors were caused by my dataset, so I proceed mocking it, but it didn't work. Then I tried mocking the object "options" passed to the function `Highcharts.stockChart(domElement, options)` but again, it didn't work.
Even a clean call to that function doesn't work: `Highcharts.stockChart(domElement, {})`

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-qdw6ll
(file tds-chart.component.ts - look at Chrome DevTools console to see the error messages)

This is the code of my component (check the function `updateOrCreateChart`):

```js
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  NgZone,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, Options } from 'highcharts';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';

@Component({
  selector: 'tds-chart',
  template: '<div id="myDiv"></div>',
  exportAs: 'tdsChart',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
// tslint:disable-next-line: component-class-suffix
export class TdsChart implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  private _options$ = new BehaviorSubject<Options>(null);
  private _sub: Subscription;
  private _chart: Chart;

  @Input() constructorType: string;
  @Input() oneToOne = false;
  @Input() runOutsideAngular = true;
  @Input() callbackFunction: (chart: Chart) => void;

  @Input() set options(val: Options) {
    this._options$.next(val);
  }

  get chart() {
    return this._chart;
  }

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private _zone: NgZone,
    private _cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._sub = this._options$.subscribe(() => this.wrappedUpdateOrCreateChart());
  }

  redraw() {
    this._options$.next(this._options$.value);
  }

  private wrappedUpdateOrCreateChart() {
    if (this.runOutsideAngular) {
      this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.updateOrCreateChart();
          this._cd.markForCheck();
        }, 1);
      });
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.updateOrCreateChart();
        this._cd.markForCheck();
      }, 1);
    }
  }

  private updateOrCreateChart() {
    if (this._chart) {
      // to do 
    } else {
      this._chart = Highcharts.stockChart('myDiv', {}, null);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this._sub) {
      this._sub.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this._chart) {
      this._chart.destroy();
      this._chart = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue open](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13437) on highcharts about this bug.

In the issue is reported a workaround for **8.0.1+** versions.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/74m9sf8c/

```js
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(
    H.Navigator.prototype,
    'drawMasks',
    function(proceed, zoomedMin, zoomedMax) {
      if (!H.isNumber(zoomedMin) || !H.isNumber(zoomedMax)) {
        return;
      }
      proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
    }
  );
})(Highcharts);
```